# Do not hyphenate words at an explicit hyphen such as in words starting "non-"

Tags: hyphenation, wordbreak

In my document, I don't want to break any words following the text `non-`, example, `non-linear`, `non-stationary`, etc.

I'm using `Windows7` and `10`, and `MikTeX 2.9` and `LaTeX-dvips-ps2pdf`

Please advise....

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\frenchspacing

with $K$ and $D$ the spring damping coefficients. A relationship between non-convex $K$ and $D$ can ensure that the target value is reached and that no overshoot occurs. As robots cannot move arbitrarily fast, the parameters $K$ and $D$ must be set in such a way to ensure that the path is {\em dynamically} feasible. When the robot moves along a straight line, bounds on the parameters can be set relatively easily. However, there are many reasons why the straight line may be neither desirable nor feasible---for instance, when the robot must avoid obstacles, or when must grasp an it must grasp object particular (e.g., the nonlinear and the robot needs to accelerate and decelerate along the way, computing the optimal path becomes more challenging. One approach is to decompose the path through a series of straight lines, called {\em splines}, or a series of polynomials. A large variety of approaches have been offered to perform this decomposition (see). However, spline decomposition works well, so long as the environment is static.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By default TeX doesn't hyphenate words with hard hyphen (on the contrary, to hyphenate such word it's necessary to either use babel's "= explicitly, or to use tricks like \hyphenchar\font=127).

Comment: a mwe is required as this should not happen so if you have an example of an additional hyphen being added in `non-stationary` that would indicate a non standard configuration somewhere.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sure, will add...

Comment: ah that's not what your question implied. That is breaking at the explicit hyphen not hyphenating the following text I'll post an answer

Comment: I have to say I'm surprised at your reluctance. What's wrong with breaking a hyphenated word at the obvious place?

Comment: @TonyK One of my Professor like this, what to do? Can't understand the Professor's mind ....I already explained her, but she still stand on the same point....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The penalty for breaking at an explicit hyphen is `\exhyphenpenalty` which by default is 50, but you can add `\exhyphenpenalty=10000` so it never breaks there.

Or you can use some number less than 10000 to discourage a break but allow it in really difficult lines.  500 is enough to discourage a break in your example.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\exhyphenpenalty=500
\begin{document}
\frenchspacing

with $K$ and $D$ the spring damping coefficients. A relationship
between non-convex $K$ and $D$ can ensure that the target value is
reached and that no overshoot occurs. As robots cannot move
arbitrarily fast, the parameters $K$ and $D$ must be set in such a way
to ensure that the path is {\em dynamically} feasible. When the robot
moves along a straight line, bounds on the parameters can be set
relatively easily. However, there are many reasons why the straight
line may be neither desirable nor feasible---for instance, when the
robot must avoid obstacles, or when must grasp an it must grasp object
particular (e.g., the nonlinear and the robot needs to accelerate and
decelerate along the way, computing the optimal path becomes more
challenging. One approach is to decompose the path through a series of
straight lines, called {\em splines}, or a series of polynomials. A
large variety of approaches have been offered to perform this
decomposition (see). However, spline decomposition works well, so long
as the environment is static.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's working like a champ....You are one of a great...Hats off to you....